# mongosb replica set server state confusion

Tags: mongodb, replication

When I tried to add a new node to current replica set, the current PRIMARY node always changed to other state (say RECOVERING )? why  is this happening ?

How can I manually update the state of a replica set server/node?

Comment: How many nodes do you have in your replica set before / after adding the new node?

Comment: Does it stay in a RECOVERING state, or recover quickly? In some cases, changing the configuration of a Replica Set will cause a new primary election.  Which version of MongoDB are you using?

Comment: I'm having a very similar issue here. I have 3 nodes in a repl set sitting on a server, say mongo1. The set is healthy with a primary and 2 secondaries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any reconfiguration of your replica set will cause a new election, and any caught-up member may be elected primary, not just your current primary. If a new primary is elected, the old primary has to pass through the RECOVERING state while it checks to see if it has all the data that the new primary has. If your set is healthy, the old primary should only spend a few seconds in RECOVERING before it becomes SECONDARY.